# Best way to adding existing javascript code with AMP Tags?

Tags: jquery, nopcommerce, amp-html

We are replacing our existing nopcommerce website with amp tags but we got stuck in Adding our custom Js code can anybody suggest what is best way to do this .

Comment: better to add in footer on bottom under `$(document).ready(function(){..});`

Answer (score 0):

AMP is a way to build fast rendering web page. In order to achieve this, AMP does not support external js. AMP have its own **AMP JS library** for more information [**CLICK HERE**](https://www.ampproject.org/learn/overview/)

You can take the help of these website for AMP

[AMP BY EXAMPLE](https://ampbyexample.com/)

[AMP START](https://www.ampstart.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The main goal to implement AMP for your site is to make it faster and to achieve that AMP does not support External js. Instead of adding custom js AMP has defined there own component [**please check here**](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components)

If you don't find your component as per your need you can request it [**here**](https://www.ampproject.org/support/developer/get_support).